# Conditonal set options in proto from command line

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto, protoc

I need to generate both generic and grpc services from a proto file, say

1. set option `cc_generic_services` to true on Linux, and use a non-grpc implementation, and
2. set option `cc_generic_services` to false on Windows, to use grpc services.

Is there any way to set the option from the command line to use one proto file.

I use cmake to manage the project files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I use `configure_file` to dynamicly generate the `proto` files based on whether `generic_services` is enabled.

In the `proto.in`, define

```proto
option cc_generic_services = @GENERIC_SERVICES@;
```

Then set `GENERIC_SERVICES` in the `CMakeLists.txt` based on whether `gRPC` is enabled.